# Ionic iOS build working in iPhone but not working in iPAD

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, build

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWbgT.png)I have taken the from the ionic ios, the build open in XCode run to iPhone its woking but run to iPad not working please find the image

please find it

Comment: Where is Image?

Comment: click to enter image description here! then view the image

Comment: Have a look https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/16

Comment: What is os version of your iPad?

Comment: iPad version 9.3.5